# From Relative Path to Full Path

Tags: batch-file

How do I get the full path of a relative path setting?

Example:

```
SET BACKUP=.\BACKUP

Echo %BACKUP% -- .\BACKUP
```

What is the special characters that I need to append?

and I don't wish to use

```
SET BACKUP=%CD%\BACKUP
```

Comment: Why exactly do you wish to not use the solution to your problem? `.` is the current directory. `%CD%` is the full path to that directory.

Comment: because I am looking for other solution, to excite my brain..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET BACKUP=.\BACKUP
Echo %BACKUP% -- .\BACKUP
```

This will never work. You can have a lot of relative `.\BACKUP` paths in you system. How can Windows know, what you mean?
You can search for a `.\BACKUP` path:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad \BACKUP*') do if "%%~nxa"=="BACKUP" echo(%%~a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%A in ("%BACKUP%") echo %%~fA
```